# How can I resolve iOS 14 breaking my app (published on the app store)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, swiftui

I have an app that is live on the App Store, and I got a screen recording from someone with an iOS 14 preview build that showed the game was unplayable. I tested this out for myself by using an xCode 12 beta version and running the app on an iOS 14 simulator, and, indeed the application was unplayable. I think this is because the app is a game and I coded it in SwiftUI, rather than GameKit, due to several optimizations. The current app version itself has no bugs, but I'm very concerned because once iOS 14 releases, the hundreds of devices the app is installed on, will all not let their users play the game.

How can I contact apple about this?

Comment: You would generally not contact Apple about this. It is your responsibility to update your game to work with iOS 14 and submit it to App Store. This is why we get beta versions. Regularly updating your apps to work with the latest version of iOS is a standard part of every iOS dev's life.

Comment: (If you discover that there is a specific bug in iOS 14 that is causing this issue, you can use Feedback Assistant to alert Apple, but you shouldn't expect it to be fixed before iOS 14 ships. You'll still need to update your app to deal with it.)

Comment: Okay thank you Rob, will Apple force users to update the app? Or is there some way I can prevent users with iOS 14 from playing the app?

Comment: since they can pretty much get an unlimited high score and break the game with the iOS14 update, unfortunately

Comment: You still have a few weeks to fix the bug.

Comment: okay thank you, it has been fixed :) - first app ever released on the App Store so I was just a bit surprised but I understand now, thank you all for helping.

Comment: No, Apple won't force an update, and since you can't change versions already installed (that would require an update…). The only way to address this is if you have a server of your own that can block previous versions of the app.

Comment: Other notes, since you're new at this. (1) Normally Apple sends out a notice that you can upload your app using the new version of Xcode (in this case 12 and iOS 14) around now. I say normally because this year the pandemic meant WWDC was about three weeks late, and rumors have it that the iPhones may be released in October instead of September. Usually developers get a good two weeks lead time to submit their apps. (2) If your app works fine in iOS versions below iOS 14 *and* you don't want to update those devices, you *can* make your update available only for iOS 14.